# How to compute Basis-transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation

I have the given matrix

```
{{-1, 4}, {5, -3}}
```

which is is the simplest representation of the two bases:
$$\mathscr{B}=[b_1,b_2]$$ and $$\mathscr{C}=[c_1,c_2]$$

where $b_1=-c_1+4c_2$ and $b_2=5c_1-3c_2$

How do I find the transformation matrix with mathematica for the transformation $\mathscr{B}\rightarrow\mathscr{C}$?

Also how do I find the coordinate vector $[x]_c$ when it is given that $[x]_b=[1,2]$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
m = {{-1, 4}, {5, -3}} ;

Array[b, 2] == m . Array[c, 2] 

Solve[Array[b, 2] == m . Array[c, 2], {b[1], b[2], c[1], c[2]}, Reals] 

Inverse[m] . Array[b, 2]
```

[image]

Or if you care about nice formatting

```
Format[c[n_]] := Subscript[c, n];
Format[b[n_]] := Subscript[b, n]; 

MatrixForm[
    m = {{-1, 4}, {5, -3}}
]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[TraditionalForm/@Thread[ Array[b, 2] == m . Array[c, 2]  ]]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[TraditionalForm/@Thread[ Array[c, 2] == Inverse[m].Array[b, 2] ]]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[TraditionalForm/@Thread[ Array[c, 2] == Inverse[m].{1,2} ]]
```

[image]

Comment: How does your solution include the coordinate vector [1,2]?

Answer (score 7):

The matrix: basec2b= {{-1, 4}, {5, -3}} maps the c base vectors to the b base vectors:

```
baseb == basec2b . basec
```

A vector: vec with coordinates: coordc in the c base and coordb in b base is:

```
vec == coordc . basec == coordb . baseb
```

Now as baseb == basec2b . basec we can write

```
vec == coordc . basec ==  coordb .  basec2b . basec
```

Therefore, as we have basec on the right side in both cases:

```
coordc == coordb .  basec2b
```

Or

```
coordb == coordc . Inverse[basec2b]
```

Finally you example with coordb= {1,2}:

```
coordc == {1,2} . {{-1, 4}, {5, -3}}  == {9,-2}
```

Comment: But what is $basec$ here?

Comment: baseb is base b and basec is base c.

Comment: @Vangsnes I believe baseb would be the starting vector represented in base b, and basec would be that same vector but represented in base c. If I understand your original post, you refer to these as $[x]_b$ and $[x]_c$.

Comment: No, this is a misunderstanding. baseb means the base vectors of b. The coordinates of some vectors are named coordb and cooordc.